# Which one is the correct dialogue punctuation format?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, punctuation, dialogue

I am writing my first novel and this the very first confusion I would like to clarify. As I am not a native English speaker, I find it very hard to understand the punctuation scheme in direct speeches.

Which one of the following is correct? Please explain why the other one is wrong.

> “I did what I needed to do.” He lowered his head to look at my face.
>
> “You should've waited for me,” she replied.

or

> “I did what I needed to do,” he lowered his head to look at my face.
>
> “You should've waited for me,” she replied.

Also, how well does this punctuation rules apply for action tags like - `he shrugged`, `he smile`, `he scoffed` and similar tags.

Comment: You are the author. You decide. Clearly it makes more sense to have two separate sentences be two separate sentences, but if you want to write an entire novel without using a single period, go ahead.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Thanks. But isn't it a grammatical violation?

Comment: They mean different things. Please visit [writers.se]

Comment: Suggesting migration to [writers.se]

Comment: @Kris Could you please explain me the difference?

Comment: Lara, as already said, I believe this better discussed on writers Q&A. Let's wait and see if the post gets migrated there.

Comment: The modern usage of novel quote verbs ('That's one way of looking at it!/,' he bellowed // shrugged / smiled // persisted) has become  frequent enough to be considered acceptable. Adding an adverb/ial (... ,' he smiled sweetly) is not a vast change. But adding a transitive independent clause requires a separate sentence. The first version is the correct one (a quote verb is often considered unnecessary nowadays if context identifies the speaker etc).

Comment: [Downing and Locke_English Grammar: A University Course](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8d2cbgSAxicC&pg=PA301&lpg=PA301&dq=%22quoted+speech+in+conversation+and+written+dialogue%22&source=bl&ots=BEwqGLPatj&sig=6VT9tczZlEy9JLlZxgbPQjggnms&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SEgMVb39KsXWUcWWhLgG&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22quoted%20speech%20in%20conversation%20and%20written%20dialogue%22&f=false) has a useful list of quotative verbs, usefully classified (and including 'non-utterance emotive verbs accompanying speech'). I've added coo; roar // smirk; wink // grimace / frown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first sentence:

> “I did what I needed to do.” He lowered his head to look at my face.

..is grammatically correct. However, being two distinct sentences implies that the character lowered his head after he spoke. I think that in general, the second sentence would precede the first:

> He lowered his head to look at my face. “I did what I needed to do.”

It's more dramatic, somewhat more menacing.

The second sentence:

> “I did what I needed to do,” he lowered his head to look at my face.

..isn't grammatically correct. The sentence construction is incorrect, because the action that follows the speech has a different subject (the speaker's head).

To correct it, you need a link from the speech to the other action. Here, you could use one of the other verbs you mentioned, all of which have the preceding speech as the subject, like this:

> “I did what I needed to do,” he [said|smiled|shrugged|scoffed], lowering his head to look at my face.